# Authentication of the request failed. GoogleAdsapis POSTMAN call

Tags: authentication, postman, google-ads-api

[image: Can Any body tell mw what is it I am doing wrong]

I am using google ads api, I have generated Access Token, Refresh Token, I have CustomerId of my Ads Manager account, my developer token still getting this error. **My ultimate goal is to generate Keyword ideas using google ads api **

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your generated token inside your **request-header**. With that token inside the header, every request to your API is authorized.

You can see that you have an *"Authorization"*-Token with the empty value *"Bearer"*. There you have to put in your token, that your API can check the token and validate it. Same thing with the *developer-token*. Your requests sends empty header values.

Comment: I know this, I just removed my authorization token and developer token from header for security purpose.

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}